# php searchform with multistring?

Tags: php, forms

Don't know if the title is right but my problem is that i got this adress

```
index?system&search&result=query
```

How should i make that work in a form? to go to that address and show output?

if i enter the url it's fine I get querys and output. But when i try with form I only get `?result=query`

Comment: how the form looks like? Also, `?=system` is there a typo? because like this is not a correct query string

Comment: That was a typo of me, at this moment i got this 

`<form class="searchform" action="index.php?system=search" method="GET">   
<input type="text" name="result" class="form-control"></form>` don't know if it should be POST or GET, get have worked befor when using pages like search.php?query= 

My only output i get is index?result=query and not the whole adress as a would like to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kinda solved it by using session if anyone interested

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
$_SESSION['search'] = strip_tags($_POST['search']);
echo "
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            self.location='index.php?system=search&result=".$_SESSION['search']."'
        </script>";
}
?>

<form method='post'> <section class='colh col-4'>
   <input type='text' name="search">
   <input type='submit' name="psubmit" value="sök">
</form>
```